# VSCode - Go to previews opened component Macro

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to know what is the macro combination to navigate into the previous componenet that I had opened in the editor.

I mean:

I work on page1.html

I go to page2.html

Then I wan't to come back to the previous component ( page1.html ).

Do you know what is the correct keys combination for Windows Environment?

Thanks to support

Answer (score 1):

The `Go Back` command will do that, but you may have to press it several times since it will first retrace your navigation in the present file.

The keyboard shortcut for that in Windows is <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> (On Mac it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>)